# how does JavaMail getSentDate get me the right local time?

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I know that in the email header, the sent date is represented relatively to UTC, but when I use the getSentDate(), it shows me the right local time.

In order to prevent future errors, I would like to know how exactly does that happen? How does JavaMail know my timezone and converts the Sent date from the header correctly?
I'll mention that in my code I never specified a timezone.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaMail doesn't do it, it's the JDK Date class.  It asks your operating system for your local timezone.

Comment: I got the wrong time from getSentDate() exactly the UTC difference of my local time. What can be?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  If the Date: header in your message includes a timezone, JavaMail uses it.  If it doesn't (although it should), JavaMail uses UTC.  What exactly is in the Date: header in your message?

Comment: This is the header: **Received: (qmail 18391 invoked by uid 89); 15 Nov 2013 07:54:17 -0000** The webmail read mail time as 08:54 and my java app read it as 09:54. I'm on GMT+1.

Comment: And this is the "Date" header: **Date: Fri, 15 Nov 2013 08:54:00 +0000** is it missing the GMT?

Comment: The date in the header is UTC/GMT.  I don't know what you mean by "my java app read it as".  Do you really mean "my java app displays it as"?  If you display it in your local time zone, it's going to be 9:54.  Unless you do something special, it's always going to be displayed in your local time zone.